# Photoshop brush strokes get lighter when overlap

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

It may be a nooby question, but I've just started to use Photoshop. My problem is that whatever brush I use, with any blending mode in any project, brush strokes become lighter when they overlap each other. It makes any kind of work impossible. I have no idea how to fix it and I can't find the solution anywhere, so I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you using light color on a dark background? Sorry for the being shallow but sometimes it is the most obvious answer that fixes problem.

Comment: Sounds like your opacity is set to < 100%. Set that to 100% and your brush will be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your brush tool, and check the blending mode in the properties section...When I have this issue with my brush overlapping and getting brighter its usually because my brush > blending mode is on screen...maybe if you just set that to normal...I'm wondering if its this because the other "blending mode" area is in the layers panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Things to check.

- brush blending mode is set to Normal
- brush Opacity and Flow are at 100%
- layer Blending Mode is set to Normal
- layer Opacity and Fill are set to 100%

Also certain brushes may have an inherent texture, overlapping strokes made with such brushes will give a natural build up. Not much you can do there.

Other possibilities are that there might be brush presets applied to the brush. Check the Brush presets for options such as wet edges, transfer, dual brush, etc - since these can cause build up effects.

If all else fails and you can't find the culprit, as a last resort, you could reset Photoshop's preferences. Instructions on how to do that appear on the Adobe website.